# Sending Request using HTTPS in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, weblogic

My C++ application consists of posting out through an HTTP connection directly to the Weblogic App server. Need to change it to post using HTTPS.

**Im running this application through Visual Studio. **

Any kind of suggestions are welcome.  Coding updates are most helpful

The below is the code i have for HTTP connectivity works fine.

**What i need to do it to work with HTTPS?**

```
      strFormData = sFile;

strHeaders  = _T("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

CInternetSession session;
CHttpConnection* pConnection =  session.GetHttpConnection(_T(Server), Port);

CHttpFile* pFile =  pConnection->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_POST,   _T(Action));                

result = pFile->SendRequest(strHeaders,(LPVOID)(LPCTSTR)strFormData,  
                                          Data.GetLength());
```

Comment: Not a direct answer, but a possible alternative: http://cpp-netlib.org/

Comment: I would look into using the boost library. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CHttpFile* pFile = pConnection->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_POST, _T(Action), NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE);
```

I tried this code and it worked out for HTTPS posting.
I found that parametric values (Internet secure flag) varies with HTTP & HTTPS posting.

Comment: Finally you got your own answer :)

Comment: ok. remove the above comment , wch is not related to this answer :)